# What's considered the best table sorting indicator?

Tags: sorting, indicator

I've got a 'classic' table which has table heads with field names in it:

[image: Table example]

There are a lot of ways to display an sorting indicator in a table:

- Upwards and downwards triangles after the active field name
- Making field names of the active field bold/underlined
- Change the color of the active field

What's considered the best method to indicate an active table field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion using upward and downward triangles is the best way, because they are unambiguous and easy to interpret.